# Getting a pdf file from a website and writing to disk

Tags: python

I have some code reading a URL and writing to disk. Here it is -

```
    url = 'http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ninghui/courses/Spring06/lectures/lecture05.pdf'
    ret = requests.get(url)
    print ret.headers
    print ret.headers['content-encoding']
    print ret.headers['content-type']

    pathToWrite = 'tmp/test.pdf'

    try:
        fd = os.open(pathToWrite, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT)

        try:
            os.write(fd, ret.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print 'cannot write to file ' + pathToWrite
            raise

        try:
            os.close(fd)
        except:
            print 'cannot close file ' + pathToWrite
            raise

    except:
        print 'file cannot be opened ' + pathToWrite
        raise
```

With the above code I can get and write a pdf file to disk I get the following error -

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 12-13: character maps to <undefined>
```

I get the same error when I use the following API -

```
f = open(pathTowWrite, 'wb')
f.write(ret.text)
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious. This seems too straightforward to go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to write `ret.content` not `ret.text`. `ret.text` tries to conver the PDF to Unicode, which is probably impossible for a binary format like PDF.

Also, you can just use the builtin open function. No need for the low-level `os.open` here.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know there is a ret.contents as well. I used the .text for html and thought I could do that for pdf too. It of course makes sense that the .text will try to convert to unicode. Btw I think its content and not contents. I just checked.